# function to automatically remove special characters from file names during saving in MacOS X

Tags: macos, filenames, string-manipulation

I'm often creating PDF files from web pages in MacOS X (10.6) and very often I have the problem that the automatically proposed file name (based on the name of the web page) contains many special characters.

So I wonder: is there an easy way (apple script, shell script, OS X service) which takes a string (like this file name) and converts it by

- removing all spaces and other special characters (also those which might be allowed in OS X, but forbidden in Windows or Linux!! as I'm often transferring files to our PC)
- maybe starting each word (after a removed space) with an uppercase letter
- ... what else could be important?

I'm using Quicksilver, so maybe it could be possible to create a command which makes it possible to replace the current text selection (in the file save as... dialog) by a converted string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an Automator service to do this in all applications that support services (which is almost all of them).

---

Open Automator and select to create a *Service* that receives *selected text* in *any application* and check *Output replaces selected text*.

Add a single *Run Shell Script* action from the library, and paste the following script code:

```
sed 's|[^a-zA-Z0-9]||g'
```

This specific script, a simple `sed` substitution will remove all non alpha-numeric characters from the file name. It uses `a-zA-Z0-9` as a whitelist of allowed characters, add to it as desired.

You can do other actions as well, and chain them together. For example, `tr [A-Z] [a-z]` will lowercase everything, and `sed 's|[^a-zA-Z0-9]||g' | tr [A-Z] [a-z]` will combine the two.

Save as e.g. *Sanitize Filename*, and optionally assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*. You should be able to invoke services using Quicksilver as well, just type their name.

---

Whenever you're in a *Save as…* or similar dialog, select the suggested file name (it's selected by default):

[image]

Invoke the service *Program Menu » Services » Sanitize Filename* (or use the keyboard shortcut you invoked). It will pipe the file name through the script, and use its output to replace the selection.

[image]

---

For title-casing and removing bad characters (I also keep underscore, dot and hyphen in), the following script code seems to mostly work for me:

```
perl -ane 'foreach $wrd(@F){print ucfirst($wrd)." ";}' | sed 's|[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]||g'
```

[image]

Comment: How would one go about doing this in a Linux environment? (Or, better yet, in Cygwin.)

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as Daniel had. Create a *Service* in *Automator*. Replace the *Run Shell Script* shell with `/usr/bin/ruby`, and add the following:

```
input, output = STDIN.read, ""
input.each("\s") {|word| output << word.capitalize}
puts output.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z\-]/, '')
```

This will get you the capitalization and you can do a bit more, of course, if you know Ruby. You could trigger the Service using QuickSilver but you would need to activate your browser using AppleScript before, I guess.

[image]