# Replace all illegal characters from folders, subfolders, and files in my Dropbox folder

Tags: macos, dropbox, applescript, automator

Our office uses dropbox on Macs to organize our design projects. For several years, many of these files and folders were being saved with characters that are illegal on Windows OS. We have some Windows OS computers we need to add to our office. This has created a problem as none of those files sync properly.

I know very little about running OSX scripts, but came across this guide that almost does what I need, except I need it to work throughout all the subfolders and files as well. The person created an automator script wrapped in a program.

[Remove All Illegal Characters from All Filenames in a Given Folder](https://superuser.com/questions/617517/remove-all-illegal-characters-from-all-filenames-in-a-given-folder)

Is it possible for a script like this to include all subfolders and files as well? This script removes all spaces and special characters, but REPLACING them with an underscore would be much better if that is a possibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- The easy way to get [slhck’s script](https://superuser.com/q/617517/354511#617607)
  to search subfolders and files recursively, if you're using bash,
  is to add `shopt -s globstar` and then change `*` to `**`. 
  This will not work correctly
  if you have directories with “illegal” characters in their names. 
  You can work around this simply by running the script *n*+1 times
  where *n* is the maximum number of directories with illegal characters
  in any path. 
  For example, if you have a `f@cat` directory,
  and a `dog#` directory below that, and a `fox!` directory below that,
  you would need to run the script four times.

  I give a better way of doing that, below.
- slhck’s script really should say `mv -i` instead of `mv`. 
  If you had files named, say, `cost+tax` and `cost-tax`,
  the script will rename them both to `costtax`
  (or `cost_tax`, after we make that change). 
  This will clobber the first file with the second file. 
  The `-i` (**i**nteractive) option will cause `mv` to ask for confirmation. 
  You’ll have to handle such collisions like that manually.
- To replace “illegal” characters with underscores,
  change `${file//[^0-9A-Za-z.]}` to `${file//[^0-9A-Za-z.]/_}`
  (or, better yet, `${file//[^0-9A-Za-z._]/_}`).

So, with the above changes, [slhck’s script](https://superuser.com/q/617517/354511#617607) becomes

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in "$1"/**
do
  dir="$(dirname "$f")"
  file="$(basename "$f")"
  mv -i -- "$f" "${dir}/${file//[^0-9A-Za-z._]/_}"
done
```

When running this,
be absolutely sure to provide an argument (e.g., **`.`**);
otherwise it will try to rename all files in the file system
(starting at `/`). 
You should probably put something in the script
to verify that the `$1` argument is not null.

---

This has problems with directories with illegal characters in their names
because the `**` expands to a list of all the files and directories
in the sub tree under `$1` with branches in top-to-bottom order. 
So, if you have `f@cat/dog#`,
it will see `f@cat` and `f@cat/dog#` as arguments. 
So it will rename `f@cat` to `f_cat`, and then look for `f@cat/dog#`
— which no longer exists, because it has been renamed to `f_cat/dog#`. 
We can fix that by doing

```
find "$1" -depth -name '*[^0-9A-Za-z._]*' -exec sh -c \
          'for f do dir="$(dirname "$f")"; file="$(basename "$f")";
          mv -i -- "$f" "${dir}/${file//[^0-9A-Za-z.]/_}"; done' sh {} +
```

The `-depth` option to `find` tells it
to look at directory branches in bottom-to-top order. 
The `-name` directive causes it to look only at file names
that *need* to be renamed. 
(The other script will give error messages
when it tries to rename files to themselves,
because their names don’t have any illegal characters.) 
`find` then passes the names to a shell
that does the same thing as the script, but as a single command.