# Batch removal of special characters from file names in Linux

Tags: linux, special-characters, batch-rename

I am seeking to remove all special characters from several files' worth of downloaded .pdfs, and came across exactly the solution I was looking for, albeit in an OS X environment:

[function to automatically remove special characters from file names during saving in MacOS X](https://superuser.com/questions/399464/function-to-automatically-remove-special-characters-from-file-names-during-savin).

**Could a similar method--either using `sed` or some other function--be implemented in a Linux environment?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with the `rename` command.  If you are in the folder with the .pdf files with special characters:

```
rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' *.pdf
```

This will remove any characters from files ending in `.pdf` that are not A-Z in either case, or numbers.  You can add to this list:

```
rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]//g' *.pdf
```

This version allows underscores.

Comment: follow-up question: Would you know how to do this when the filename contains letters that aren't from English alphabet?

When I try your commands I get "Can't rename `filename`: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character" for each file.

Comment: @user2044638 Are you able to rename these files with a `mv`?

Comment: Yes. Worked for every file I tried it on without problems.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to be working for me. I installed the requisite util-linux package, and while it appears to run, there is no change in file names. Is there documentation for "rename" somewhere?

Comment: @nitrl There are two separate "rename" utilities, one supports regex, the other doesn't.  Check your man page to see which one you have.

Comment: @Paul I am using the 2.21 release of util-linux, which oddly enough doesn't seem to include a "rename" utility (ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/v2.21-ReleaseNotes). The 2.23 release appears to include one (ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/v2.23-ReleaseNotes). Perhaps an upgrade is in order?

Comment: @wjandrea Feel free to edit answers to enhance them.

Comment: On OS X, it removes the . in front of the suffix, which is kind of obvious...

Answer (score 5):

To handle the whole file name and also multiple files:

- Add `/g` to handle the whole file name.
- Add `_`to replace with underscore (if required to)
- Add any additional 'types' of files or individual file names at the end, space separated.

> rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/_/g' *mp4 *avi

Answer (score 1):

There is a very handy tool called [detox](https://github.com/dharple/detox) that will do exactly this transformation/renaming for you.

You can pass it a directory name (eventually recursing) or a pattern of specific files:

```
detox ./
```

or

```
detox *.pdf
```

It is bundle with most Linux distributions.

Answer (score -2):

for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.*-]/*/g'); done &

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: Actually the same as the accepted `rename` method but harder to enter without mistakes